# non-optional relations one-to-one failed to save with 1570 error sometimes

Tags: ios, core-data

I have Task and Person classes. Task has relationship one-to-one with Person, this relation called "assignee". I have NSManagedObject inheritors for both classes. I am getting instance of Person (with aid of NSFetchRequest), and then I create new Task (with NSEntityDescription), and

```
task.assignee = person;
[context save:&error];
```

Some times it saves, but most of the time I am getting “Cocoa Error 1570” saying "assignee" is null!

How could it be?

- I added assert(task.assignee) just before saving
- I check [task validateForInsert:&error]; AND ERROR IS EMPTY!!
- I am using the same context from which I fetched Person a second ago
- Nobody touches it in background

And the funniest thing: when I check "optional" in my relation, it works!
It saves correct data: task with person.

Is it a bug or what?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I did a stupid threading mistake.

I had context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, and used objects obtained from it on main thread, which is not allowed (managed objects are not thread safe). I should switch to `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` or use `managedObjectID` to refetch objects from different context (on the correct thread).